# Solving for endpoints given by two integral equations

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods, integral-equations

I have been trying to work out an example related to hypothesis testing for the scale parameter in an exponential distribution. By following the statistic theory I have been led to the following mathematics question.

For a fixed natural number $n$ is there a way to calculate constants $a, b >0$ that satisfy the following to equations

$$\int_a^b x^{n-1}e^{-x} dx = 0.95 \times (n-1)! ~~\text{and}~~ \int_a^b x^n e^{-x}dx = 0.95 \times n!.$$

I think I can calculate $a$ and $b$ by sampling from a Gamma distribution with scale $1$ and shape $n$ but is there a way more directly get a handle on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Newton's method maybe? It is just an algebraic system.

Comment: @michaelhowes: your original problem can likely be solved using   $\chi^2$ paper tables. If you post your problem I can show you how to do that

Comment: @tommik I want to find the uniformly most powerful unbiased test of $H_0 : \lambda = \lambda_0$ against $H_1 : \lambda \neq \lambda_0$ where we have i.i.d. data $X$ drawn from an exponential distribution with scale parameter $\lambda>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Using algebra.*

Writing the equations as
$$f_1(n)=\log \Big[\Gamma (n,a)-\Gamma (n,b)\Big]-\log \left(\frac{19}{20} (n-1)!\right)$$
$$f_2(n)=\log \Big[\Gamma (n+1,a)-\Gamma (n+1,b)\Big]-\log \left(\frac{19}{20} n!\right)$$ and defining the norm
$$\Phi(a,b)=f_1^2(n)+f_2^2(n)$$ the minimization of $\Phi(a,b)$ doe not make much problems since can easily be built the analytical Jacobian and Hessian.

Below are given some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n &    a      &      b    \\
 1 &   0.04236 &   4.76517 \\
 2 &   0.30350 &   6.40122 \\
 3 &   0.71250 &   7.94830 \\
 4 &   1.20696 &   9.43022 \\
 5 &   1.75808 &   10.8644 \\
 6 &   2.35023 &   12.2623 \\
 7 &   2.97386 &   13.6315 \\
 8 &   3.62263 &   14.9773 \\
 9 &   4.29208 &   16.3036 \\
 10 &  4.97893 &   17.6134 \\
 11 &  5.68069 &   18.9088 \\
 12 &  6.39540 &   20.1917 \\
 13 &  7.12151 &   21.4636 \\
 14 &  7.85776 &   22.7257 \\
 15 &  8.60308 &   23.9789 \\
 16 &  9.35661 &   25.2240 \\
 17 &  10.1176 &   26.4619 \\
 18 &  10.8854 &   27.6931 \\
 19 &  11.6595 &   28.9181 \\
 20 &  12.4393 &   30.1374 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The problem could also be reduced to a single variable. Using a now deleted answer from @PierreCarre, the two parameters are related by
$$e^{-a}\, a^n = e^{-b}\, b^n \implies b=-n W_{-1}\left(-\frac{a }{n}e^{-\frac{a}{n}}\right)$$ where $W_{-1}$ is the second branch of Lambert function. This reduces the problem to one equation for one unknown; this equation can easily be solve using Newton method.

For $20 \leq n \leq 100$, a quick and dirty nonlinear regression $(R^2 > 0.999999)$  gives for $a$ an estimate
$$a =\alpha + \beta \,n- \gamma \log(n)$$

$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha  & 4.06273 & 0.07949 & \{3.90441,4.22104\} \\
 \beta   & 0.93189 & 0.00051 & \{0.93087,0.93290\} \\
 \gamma  & 3.39745 & 0.02724 & \{3.34319,3.45171\} \\
\end{array}$$

Tested for $n=200$, the estimate is $a=172.440$ while the solution is $a=173.537$.

Comment: @PierreCarre. If you have time to waste, have a look at my answer and tell me if we could do it faster or better. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

UMP test does not exist for your hypotheses' system. The best test you can find is the one based  on LR but due to the 2 tails $H_1$ it is not UMP. In fact your critical region depends on the alternative hypotheses.

First observe that starting from $f_X(x|\lambda)=\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-x/\lambda}$ and using a $n$ sized random sample, MLE is $\hat{ \lambda}_{ML}=\frac{\Sigma_i x_i}{n}$

To verify your hypotheses system use generalized LR

$$\frac{ \left(\frac{1}{\lambda_0} \right)^n e^{ -\Sigma_i  x_i /\lambda_0}}{\left(\frac{n}{\Sigma_i x_i} \right)^n e^{ -n}   }\le k$$

That is

$$T^n e^{-T}\le  k^*$$

Where $T=\frac{\Sigma_ i x_i}{\lambda_0}$

Studying LHS function you easy get that it is continuous with a maximum in $T=n$ thus $T^n e^{-T}\le  k$ is equivalent to

$$T\le c_1; T\ge c_2$$

for appropriate constants $c_1,c_2$

The distribution of $T$ can be derived; in fact,under $H_0$,

$$\Sigma_i x_i\sim\text{Gamma}[n; \lambda_0]$$

and consequently

$$\frac{2}{\lambda_0}\Sigma_i x_i=2T\sim\chi_{(2n)}^2$$

Now you can solve your problem using paper tables without calculating any integral